# how to set width size in rdl using vs 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I created report vs 2008 asp .net web application and sql server 2008, report .rdl. i want to chage the height and width of the reportviewer...  width=100%

how can i do this....

plz help me....

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the rdl as XML and change either of those two elements, though I am not sure they accept percentages.

@jay - I was talking about the RDL file itself. If you are talking about the browser window that displays the report, then you can use any of the standard HTML sizing options.

Comment: ReportViewer control does not inherit the .rdl width/height properties.